# Xamarin HttpClient.PutAsync no params probmem

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin.forms, put

I have problem with httpClient.PutAsync
I am using code below, but API didnt get any of my params.

I was testing PUT via Postman and its working, but from my app API is not getting any params via PUT. Where is bug?

```
public async Task<PutResponse> PutBMI(BMIItemsPUT bmiItems)
{
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> putData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    putData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user_id", bmiItems.user_id.ToString()));
    putData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("data", bmiItems.data.ToString()));
    putData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("height", bmiItems.height.ToString()));
    putData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("weight", bmiItems.weight.ToString()));
    putData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("activity", bmiItems.activity.ToString()));
    putData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("bmi", bmiItems.bmi.ToString()));
    putData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("kcal_demand", bmiItems.kcal_demand.ToString()));
    FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(putData);
    PutResponse putdata = await PutBMIresponse<PutResponse>(Constansts.BMIUrl, content);

    return putdata;
}

public async Task<T> PutBMIresponse<T>(string weburl, FormUrlEncodedContent content) where T : class
{
    HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await client.PutAsync(weburl, content);
    string jsonResult = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Debug.WriteLine("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" + jsonResult);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonResult);
}
```

Comment: Could you share a screen from Postman with the parameters **and** HTTP request headers? And one more thing that's probably not gonna solve your problem but... is there any reason why you are not using a dictionary of string & string, but instead a list of key value pairs?

Comment: here is screen
https://postimg.cc/QHxcDhXy

I am new in c# so i am mostly copying code from tutorials, but for PUT nothing is working

Comment: here request headers https://postimg.cc/GHGfcqMN

Comment: From what I already can see you are doing some kind of authorization in Postman, which I don't see in your code. You can add authorization via `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization`. Are there other endpoints working? Are there other HTTP verbs working like HTTP GET? What I'm trying to find out is whether your problem is specific to only this particular API endpoint or in general in your API querying approach.